# What is the default registry value for Command Processor's Autorun?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, powershell, cmd.exe, autorun

Every time I tried to run cmd recently it would just pop-up and close immediately, and only Powershell worked on my pc.

I found a solution that asked me to navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` and set the Autorun file value to 0. It gave an error message saying

> '0' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

but cmd was finally working again and I didn't think anything of it. When I restarted my PC and logged in, there was a blank screen with a cmd window open giving me the same error message. But this time `explorer.exe` didn't load after I logged in and I had to open it through Task Manager. This now happens every time I restart. How can I fix this?

Comment: I would suggest running "sfc /scannow" from a command prompt started from windows 10 boot options (hold down shift and click restart when on the desktop).

Comment: It seems like you have installed some add-on to cmd, or that your computer is infected. Delete the Autorun value and test if the cmd command arrives when booting in Safe mode.

Comment: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` is blank by default. CMD is attempting to run the program called `0`. However this key has no effect whatsoever on *Explorer.exe*, only on *cmd.exe*.

Answer (score 1):

The default value for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` should be a blank, not a zero.

Comment: This should be a comment IMO

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, read the question again. It directly answers the question asked. On what basis do you believe it should be a comment?